# How can I check the time taken by k8s pod to start?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I want to know the time it takes to start my pod in Kubernetes. My pod has `3 Init Containers` and `9 actual Containers`.
Here's what I have tried so far:

- ***Approach 1:*** Start the pod and monitor until there are 9/9 containers running. The `AGE` in `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>` will give an idea for startup time.
- ***Approach 2:*** Refer to the events for the pod using `kubectl events` or `kubectl describe` command. The problem is events are not there for all containers. Also, there is no clear way to understand the time taken by pod to be in `READY` state.

[image]

**Question:** Does Kubernetes provide any way to determine the whole pod startup time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As things begin to set up, your pod will progress through a set of [PodConditions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-conditions).

You could use:

```
kubectl get po <pod_name> -o yaml
```

to observe the progression through these various conditions:

```
...
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-09-09T08:47:11Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-09-09T08:47:12Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-09-09T08:47:12Z"
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-09-09T08:47:11Z"
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
...
```

If you want to automatically parse all of this in a shell, I'd recommend [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)
for the actual YAML parsing.

Answer (score 3):

In case this can help anyone out there, here is an example using kubectl, yq and bash

```
$ kubectl -n ${NAMESPACE} get pods -o yaml | yq e '.items[].status.conditions[] | select('.type' == "PodScheduled" or '.type' == "Ready") | '.lastTransitionTime'' - | xargs -n 2 bash -c 'echo $(( $(date -d "$0" "+%s") - $(date -d "$1" "+%s") ))'
67
70
70
72
...
```

Answer (score 1):

While there is no exact mechanism for that in Kubernetes you may want to check [Kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics#:%7E:text=kube-state-metrics%20is%20a,the%20state%20of%20the%20objects.&text=It%20is%20not%20focused%20on,as%20deployments,%20nodes%20and%20pods.):

> kube-state-metrics is a simple service that listens to the Kubernetes
> API server and generates metrics about the state of the objects. (See
> examples in the Metrics section below.) It is not focused on the
> health of the individual Kubernetes components, but rather on the
> health of the various objects inside, such as deployments, nodes and
> pods.

With it you can export object creation time. The metric name in that case would be `kube_<OBJECT>_created`.  This [article](https://blog.freshtracks.io/a-deep-dive-into-kubernetes-metrics-part-6-kube-state-metrics-14f4e7c8710b) about metrics in section 6 explain more about kube state metrics and usage of object creation time.

Note that if you are about to measure your `pod start time` you have assume that all images needed to run that pod are already pre-pulled on the machine. Otherwise your measurement will not be correct as it will include variables that influence Kubernetes performance such as network or image size.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jedi's answer, I wrote the below tool to do this using https://stedolan.github.io/jq/.  I run it like this: `for pod in $(kubectl get --no-headers=true pods -o name | awk -F "/" '{print $2}'); do  ./get-pod-boot-time $pod ; done`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pod="$1"

fail() {
    echo "$@" 1>&2
    exit 1
}

# https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-conditions
get_condition_time() {
    condition="$1"

    iso_time=$(kubectl get pod "$pod" -o json | jq ".status.conditions[] | select(.type == \"$condition\" and .status == \"True\") | .lastTransitionTime" | tr -d '"\n')

    test -n "$iso_time" || fail "Pod $pod is not in $condition yet"

    date -d $iso_time +%s
}

initialized_time=$(get_condition_time PodScheduled)
ready_time=$(get_condition_time Ready)
duration_seconds=$(( $ready_time - $initialized_time ))

echo "It took $duration_seconds seconds for $pod to boot up"
```