# Get the elapsed time of kubernetes pod in terminating state

Tags: kubernetes

Hi I need to get all the pods in a cluster which are in terminating state for more than 2 minutes.

Ex : I delete a pod, it went to terminating state. Usualy the pod get deletes within a minute. But there are some scenarios pod was in terminating state for a long time. How can get this pod list, any way to achieve this.?

Also is there any way I can force a pod in terminating state for sometime to test this.?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50338057/21404450

Comment: This helps in force deleting pods in terminating state. The idea is to get telemetry out of pods in terminating state for a long time

Comment: mmm... https://stackoverflow.com/a/70458196/21404450 ; You could work on a bash script incorporating commands like these to export the time the Pod is in a certain state.